# How to simplify a TypeScript type lookup map

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm looking for a way to simplify the following.

I have a simple record type:

```js
type Foo<Name extends keyof FooMap, Value> = {
  name: Name;
  value: Value;
};
```

where `Value` can be anything from a simple to complex type.

And also a lookup that contains a key (which maps to the `Name` attribute of the record) and target `Value`s:

```js
type FooMap = {
  a: {
    complex: string;
    type?: boolean;
  };
  b: string;
  c: number;
};
```

I'd like to have a type that I can use in the following way:

```js
<Name extends keyof FooMap>({ name, value }: Foo<Name, FooMap[Name]>) => {
  if (name === 'a') {
    if (value.type ?? false) {
      strings.push(value.complex);
    }
  }

  if (name === 'b') {
    strings.push(value);
  }

  if (name === 'c') {
    while (strings.length < value) {
      strings.push(strings[strings.length % Math.min(strings.length, value)]);
    }
  }
};
```

but the naive version here doesn't work as expected and `value` is always a union of the possibilities.

I've managed to make it work around it using the following map structure instead:

```js
type FooMap = {
  a: Foo<'a', {
    complex: string;
    type?: boolean;
  }>;
  b: Foo<'b', string>;
  c: Foo<'c', number>;
};

<Name extends keyof FooMap>({ name, value }: FooMap[Name]) => {
  if (name === 'a') {
    if (value.type ?? false) {
      strings.push(value.complex);
    }
  }

  if (name === 'b') {
    strings.push(value);
  }

  if (name === 'c') {
    while (strings.length < value) {
      strings.push(strings[strings.length % Math.min(strings.length, value)]);
    }
  }
};
```

but I feel like the duplication could be avoided.

Am I missing a key concept here, or am I trying to do something that's beyond the general use-case?

[TS playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=76&ssc=1&pln=93&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsFNQIwIYGcCWBjUKAu0C2AoLATwAdYAxAe0oB4A5BXWaADxwDsATJUAa2iKUAZqCqUAsghIAaUADUEAGwCu0AHygAvKADe%20UKHaNoALlAMmAbn2gAbktVmFK6NYC%201-CAgxMnaEqguFKEpBTUkiRaujYIZnoGBmiUuCSKrGZIWABOKOwA5taJoMRkAPxmcNTpCOxFoB42cJk5eYU2aGbsyrhw0Nnunt5QKDwA7pTZvDzIoP6o2dCcsnDKWHPKaegIODxYvhbQoWSiEVIATNEJoHGntADkCPey10kpaRmgWbkF9Qal0Aq8GqATqNjcanqzTuNHucGeX1aBUhHTMYlhaAR3V6-RRjS8YBGPE4lGgSHY93WEymoGg2Bg2VAAApZthMFxWGSSr4SNlKGRslgUFzhNzYAhstkEEQVmsxYsgih8pB1n0bqAxtKSpQggh%20JgqZNeGYAKJsKVoLA0fiCERiSIAZlk2L62TUsvWQmg0EUPGS7FslBUOE4ZQAlMdwhIpA7ogBtGzox4I16gZKpdIsFo-drFAFAqpB0H1CHSRPUWHw2TfNru8sPTHOnquusAXSGhMgo0wPHYOs4KCEXsW7HWWB19qkHtAAEluZRlMr1mzcEqVRqjdrdVFsNOhAgUL6br7KJG7pEACxXGxxw7svgCUWTkittEVw6yZ%2034yttT4Nz4ASPiwEgxg3DMVS2LAqzrLgkywIo2D9EoZ7PgArNeBjfkw942k%20ZwvvENgGEYTBmIcfx2A4pjnlI2HQO24LuIB3gALTsRxnFcdxPG8Xx-ECQJQEACI9LgRBzDsCD4P6WSIjmSDZm0catvGNj3Hk2AoEozz4IxQFEqA%206Hkg%20D0GBrAcNwD62rRJBqEyOiGMYsj2C4DRvrQH52fRv5hloGjXIOzKkbAmjhaAyb%20amwVMm5qgAHQAqAZRlEZShINA0XEYkNYFEgCUkMoSCQHF1EJemHwsGGlEAQYAE2LFoVaBFcL3NlxR5fkBVFSVZUuDV4KAQYTVgeF2j3JiHWJGMXbpMyXUFekBT7KANBUQNMTFAYi2FcVpWLXGu3Lfkq0AKSgJI%20wJau7BMsd0ArZArnUWGraDcUdUNP%20HY%20N21LTNOc4khS6yIfq%20ywJwmyIWgOwoJQ7BmXelmPdZeF2gR5wOU5oUve5bieZE5y%20f5miBY1IhMs142RU800jVT8XQElYQpWl%206%20llW3bbtvWlczFXvJmH2JF9DWMyFY2tfCDPyW0PX7f1qiixLmBUzTrVTTzBizYesD3Ui3UJSdq3rczcs7Ubit9YdD1PaAF1XZAN15IbCkm49p3PRtKvvbVQ34sMXY8MZvpmTOHIsLSbBozwGN2Q6OPOUw%20OqB5idxpH-gsO9AU86NOG01FOvq8ygvJal6Vc5b8v5XtfWC5VIsB-Vw1l9T0sTbLpd80rFslu3hdhVr7Wl3r83uwrnsO%20br2l1bHv81P%20VHdbM-e47l07C7t0r8bps%20xb-s5eLP0sZ23Zh6Z5k4ajXDx4%20mPRiQF7J3jvuwITdkXqT%20dBRrLudMx4xSZuVSuHMMrc1TIvaey8m7C1YKLNubdKZSyLjLEBOU%206N1eoPNBncMETW1qmCeBt7abznptGBddjbLztuvQ%20W9nauzuhQ-Yacson0%20oHX6hlr7IwsrHB%20Nl8IvzQu-Fyn8M7oT-uTAugCiHALlrFCubMq6c0yrXHBAtyrNyQa3b6BDNbdywZ1de8C8FDWMUAyaZiZpzXIYwr2ZtP7aIsUrBhHsmFOx3qw-eS0XFH1etwsWvD8BAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N55EoN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think so, yeah! Thanks! I guess I was close with `FooMap4` but needed to move the index from the usage to the definition which is somewhat counterintuitive to me! 

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance; it might not be for a number of hours.

Comment: That's fine, I appreciate the info. It'd be great (if you know what it is) to have some clarity on why the `type` needs the index onto the map, rather than the usage (the type hint in the function) but I'll take an answer for sure!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what "why the `type` needs the index onto the map, rather than the usage (the type hint I'm the function)" means; could you demonstrate with code?

Comment: Apologies for the bad explanation and delay, I'm working on mobile whilst I put my youngest to bed! Basically I've converted `FooMap4` to meet your example and the only difference is the `[keyof FooMap]` in the definition, where I had it in the type definition of the function argument (albeit as `[Name]`). https://gist.github.com/dom111/9fede337d53758244a0a8485244b1beb Gist because playground URL was too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is checking the `name` variable against the different possibilities in turn, and using the results of those checks to narrow the `value` variable.  The only way that sort of control flow is supported by TypeScript is when `{name, value}` is seen as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) which you [destructure into](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) separate `name` and `value` variables.  While conceptually it shouldn't matter if `{name, value}` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), the compiler treats generics differently.  A rule of thumb is that discriminated unions are good for case-by-case analysis (i.e., different blocks of code for different cases), while generics are good for a single case which can be generalized (i.e., one block of code whose types can be different).

---

So first let's generate that union type:

```
type NameValueMap<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { name: K, value: T[K] }
}[keyof T];
```

The `NameValueMap<T>` utility type makes *distributive object types* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109); by [mapping over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the properties of `T` and then immediately [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that mapped type with the full set of keys, you get a union.

Like so:

```
type FooNameValue = NameValueMap<FooMap>
/* type FooNameValue = {
    name: "a";
    value: {
        complex: string;
        type?: boolean | undefined;
    };
} | {
    name: "b";
    value: string;
} | {
    name: "c";
    value: number;
} */
```

And now we can write your function where the `{name, value}` parameter is of the union type `FooNameValue`:

```
const f = ({ name, value }: FooNameValue) => {
  if (name === 'a') {
    if (value.type ?? false) {
      strings.push(value.complex);
    }
  }

  if (name === 'b') {
    strings.push(value);
  }

  if (name === 'c') {
    while (strings.length < value) {
      strings.push(strings[strings.length % Math.min(strings.length, value)]);
    }
  }
};
```

That compiles successfully because of the support for destructured discriminated unions.  Just to be painfully clear, this works because `f` is not a generic function: its input is of a specific discriminated union type, and not a generic type constrained to a union:

```
// const f: ({ name, value }: FooNameValue) => void
```

If you make it generic (e.g., `<K extends keyof FooMap>({name, value}: SomeEquivalentType<K>) => void`), the compiler will lose the thread inside the function and complain.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAsgQzFAvFA3gKClZALmz3ygGM4BbMAGwgA9iBnYAJwEsA7AcwG5S+UJAD8xAEYJ6yLgPwBfOVHEt23fqXLEuAVyriIbAYpw5h0AHLIqEAGrJaOiCjAAeACoA+DCXwBtAGkobigAawgQOAAzKHcAXWIsKC5rCGIAgBooADcHJ2J3QLioeRx5P3DImPiBM3BoeDgrG3tHaExmuzznVFdGl08cAHoAKihzWARO1qcfXDJk1OIAImRlpXxctsTBBYpqOkZVTl4NvfMxZSkIGSgAHygdLgATCCjuCGezk3l73zIUjYVuJ1rstvkoKwThpfg95gCllBluRQQtwWlknoDEYylARkNTEMhlAACJ6KggKDPZDAZA4ShcViQtS8ZjHdR+YqYPykADk3A4wA4Dl5GRwcVqDKZMUwAAokoCIFl0SViI1pt0AJQYbzwjgxWWKjDoTC85C87Xw-D6qCy9EAOgmIhEUCiDmYEEtu3wUPUzHtYB0zAAFnbuvbKDR6AxNd9SKVSDbDaljabxBb-j6WTx-YGQ2G2rH46ZrQajSbTeQM1aoAB3YMcei232s+30XjAYNQVw5LWZsgtnMBoOhwfMPxjtsQDtdgCkUBQnftVG4ssn7Z4neVWriRYWpQUZVqRP2jOAruI8sWNm3bVVkyaqRmnp1OTgHGeOCAA)